# Phone call from Java app and receive SDP

Tags: java, sip, sdp

From a Java application, what is the best way to be able to dial a phone number (via any API or service) and receive an SDP from this endpoint?

I don't want to be able to just call a number (by using Twilio or Plivo or similar), I want to place a call but I want to have control over it, such as the other endpoint it connects to, by taking advantage of a Session Description Protocol packet.

Should I look in the SIP direction? Something like Sip trunking? I think this is the direction but it looks like there isn't a popular java SIP library to use (I've been looking at [peers](https://github.com/ymartineau/peers) but I don't know if it very good)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should definitely look for a java SIP client library.

"Peers" seems to be too minimal, lacking important functionalities such as codec support. I can recommend the mizu jvoip compact library or the more complex jitsi java client.